# Using jQuery find() inside and if conditional

Tags: jquery, if-statement, find, conditional-statements

Why does this code alert “found it” and not “nope”?

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-inner">
  <div>Another div</div>
</div>
<footer class="vc_row">Footer</footer>
```

**jQuery**

```
if ( $('.site-inner').find('.vc_row') ) {
    alert('found it');
} else {
    alert('nope');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `find()` function returns a jQuery object, not a Boolean. And like all jQuery functions, it is designed to return an empty jQuery object if the actual element is not found. Now, when you put anything inside `if()` statement, JavaScript automatically convert it to a Boolean. And the result of converting any object to a Boolean is always `true` in JavaScript.

You can see that in action by converting the result to a Boolean by yourself using `!!`. The result as you can see below is `true`:

```js
console.log(!!$('.site-inner').find('.vc_row'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-inner">
  <div>Another div</div>
</div>
<footer class="vc_row">Footer</footer>
```